# Make geom_jitter points thicker

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to adjust the thickness of geom_jitter points in ggplot without increasing the overall size.

Here is what I currently have:

```
data <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), B=c(7,8,9,4,3,5,4,3,2))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(A, B))

p + geom_jitter(pch=4, cex=8, lwd=3)
```

The script runs if I do not include the `lwd` option, but this appears to be what I am looking for to control the line width. If I include it I get a warning message: `Duplicated aesthetics after name standardisation: size`. Based on this I'm guessing `cex` and `lwd` are being interpreted as doing the same thing, which doesn't seem right to me.

How can I control for the overall size of the point (via cex), but change the thickness of the lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ggplot2 package doesn't specify properties of points the same way that base R plots do (though it makes an effort to translate). Here is a ggplot-esque way of specifying the thickness of lines ([stroke](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#colour-and-fill-1)).

```r
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), B=c(7,8,9,4,3,5,4,3,2))

p <- ggplot(data, aes(A, B))

p + geom_jitter(shape=4, size=8, stroke=3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>